# reinit bootstrap modal after ajax loaded a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div and in this div I load an button thats opens a bootstrap 3 modal:

```
<div id="test">
Here comes the button...
</div>
```

With ajax I load this button into the `div#test`:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" target="#modal">Open the modal</button>
```

But how can I reinit Bootstrap 3 (after ajax loaded the button in the div) so I can open the modal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *data-target* instead of *target* to point to your modal:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Open the modal</button>
```

There is no need to reinitialize the bootstrap 3 modals after loading the button via jax.